# On mouseover apply class to non-mouseovered elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, mouseenter

Im going to assume there is a better way to do this but here is what I want.  I have a Unordered List. When you hover on a List element it removes notHovered with hovered, all other notHovered elements are applied a BlurImage class. What I end up with is only one LI has the "BLURIMAGE" class added. Thank you for your help.

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9HbNR/1/

jQuery code

```
var flag = true;    
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('ul.hoverable li').each(function(){
            $(this).addClass('notHovered');
        });
        $('ul li').on("mouseover", function(){
            $(this).removeClass('notHovered').addClass('hovered');
            $(' ul li.notHovered').each(function(){
                if(flag == true) {
                    flag = false;
                    $(this).addClass('BlurImage');
                }
            });
        });
        $('ul li').on("mouseout", function(){
            $('.BlurImage').removeClass('BlurImage');
            $('.hovered').addClass('notHovered').removeClass('hovered');
            flag = true;
        });
    });
```

HTML CODE

```
<ul class="inline-ul full hoverable">
    <li>

</li>
    <li>

</li>
    <li>

</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Remove your flag variable. Without it, it works as you described.

Comment: I actually figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Removed the each which fixed it

```
var flag = true;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('section#tf-media .bottom ul.hoverable li').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('notHovered');
    });
    $('section#tf-media .bottom ul li').on("mouseover", function(){
        $(this).removeClass('notHovered').addClass('hovered');
            if(flag == true) {
                flag = false;
                $('section#tf-media .bottom ul li.notHovered').addClass('BlurImage');
            }
    });
    $('section#tf-media .bottom ul li').on("mouseout", function(){
        $('.BlurImage').removeClass('BlurImage');
        $('.hovered').addClass('notHovered').removeClass('hovered');
        flag = true;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use JavaScript and not pure css?

```
ul li { /* basic styles */ }
ul:hover li { /* change styles to ul that is hovered */ }
ul:hover li:hover { /* change styles to li that is hovered */ }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3K8Gh/)

Comment: Thres a specific class that gets applied. I could use Less or Sass,but this is quicker